# How to get node data by slug/alias instead of ID

Tags: drupal-8

from front dev like react or other it is usefull to get remote node data by slug instead of ID.
Drupal JSONAPI doesn't do that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not JSONAPI, it will only get the id of the object you found in your query. Then you have to change your query to search only for slug, not id and slug.

```
$query = $database->query(
      "SELECT nid
            FROM {node} n, {url_alias} a
            WHERE a.alias = '/$slug'"

    );
```

Comment: JSONAPI does not offer the possibility to get node by slug. Your SQL is wrong because you don't have a join between two tables. Two tables = one join

Answer (score -1):

route :

```
myapi.default_controller_nodebyslug:
  path: '/jsonapi_tlged/node-by-slug/{slug}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\jsonapi_tlged\Controller\DefaultController::nodeBySlug'
    _title: 'Node by slug'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

in controller :

```
  public function nodeBySlug($slug) {
    $database =  \Drupal::database();
    $query = $database->query(
      "SELECT nid
            FROM {node} n, {url_alias} a
            WHERE n.nid = SUBSTR(a.source, 7)
            AND a.alias = '/$slug'"
    );
    $result = $query->fetchObject();
    if ($result !== false) {
      $node = Node::load($result->nid);
      return new JsonResponse($node->toArray());
    }

    //return new JsonResponse(json_encode(false));
    return new JsonResponse(false);
  }
```